# MSSQL Linux Problems, port 1433 status opened from ufw, but still cannot remote or even telnet

Tags: networking, ufw, telnet, mssql

I have problem with MSSQL in Linux, and i'm installing it on Ubuntu 18.04 linux, im already open port 1433 and 1434 via ufw but still have no luck with remote connection and even from telnet, here my `netstat -an | grep "Listen"`

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1431          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1433            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8125          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:19999           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4224            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

and telnet : `telnet localhost 1433` result

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
```

Connected to localhost.localdomain.
Escape character is '^]'.

this is a test
Connection closed by foreign host.

The other port testing for remoting all is ok, except the port 1433 and 1434.

Any suggestion and help ?, really appreciate.
- Thanks

Comment: So... you can successfully establish a connection via localhost, but not from where exactly? another host in your LAN? a remote host outside the LAN?

Comment: Hello i can successfully connected into database with localhost :

'~$ sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA
Password:
1>'

But no luck from another host LAN or remote host outside. And i try telnet is from inside the box itself not from LAN or remote host.